# Lookup of base class name after inheriting constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, name-lookup, inheriting-constructors, injected-class-name

Consider the following code:

```
struct base {};

struct derived : public base {
    using base::base;
    base foo() const;  // how does name lookup on 'base' here work?
};
```

Intuitively, it's clear that this code is valid, and it does compile (tested with gcc and clang).

However, I'd like to understand what in the standard makes it valid. Specifically, I'd like to understand how name lookup for `base` in `base foo()` finds the base class type rather than the inherited constructor.

Here's my analysis of the standard wording, showing that it should resolve to the constructor. It's probably wrong, but I'd like to understand where I'm going wrong.

I started with `[class.member.lookup] p1`:

> Member name lookup determines the meaning of a name (*id-expression*) in a class scope. [...] For an *id-expression*, name lookup begins in the class scope of `this`

`p7` tells us what the result of name lookup is:

> The result of name lookup for [a member name] `f` in [a class scope] `C` is the declaration set of *S(f, C)*

I'm trying to follow this procedure with `C` being `derived`, and `f` being the use of `base` in `base foo()`.

"Declaration set" is defined in `p3`:

> The *lookup set* for `f` in `C`, called *S(f, C)*, consists of two component sets: the *declaration set*, a set of members named `f`; [...]

`p4` tells us what goes into the declaration set:

> If `C` contains a declaration of the name `f`, the declaration set contains every declaration of `f` declared in `C` that satisfies the requirements of the language construct in which the lookup occurs.

`using base::base` is a declaration of the name `base` (`f`) in `derived` (`C`). The paragraph goes on to give examples of what it means for a declaration **not** to satisfy the requirements of the language construct in which the lookup occurs, but there's nothing there that would exclude `using base::base` from this lookup.

Next, further down in `p3` we're told how *using-declarations* in the declaration set are handled:

> In the declaration set, *using-declarations* are replaced by the set of designated members that are not hidden or overridden by members of the derived class

So what members does `using base::base` designate? Seems to me like that's answered by `[class.qual] p2`:

> In a lookup in which function names are not ignored and the
>   *nested-name-specifier* nominates a class `C`:
>
> - if the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier*, when looked up in `C`, is the injected-class-name of `C`, or
> - in a *using-declaration* that is a *member-declaration*, if the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier* is the same as
>     *identifier* [...] in the last component of the *nested-name-specifier*
>
> the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class `C`.

There is a footnote which clarifies what a "lookup in which function names are not ignored" means:

> Lookups in which function names are ignored include names appearing in a *nested-name-specifier*, an *elaborated-type-specifier*, or a *base-specifier*.

None of these is the case for the name lookup in question, so it seems to me that this paragraph applies, and says that `using base::base` designates the constructor (which is also what you'd expect intuitively, given that it's the inheriting constructor declaration).

Having found a declaration (designating the base class constructor) in the derived class scope, we continue following `[class.member.lookup] p4`:

> If the resulting declaration set is not empty, the subobject set contains `C` itself, and calculation is complete.

That is, since name lookup found a result in the derived class scope, it does not proceed to look in the base class scope (where it would find the *injected-class-name* `base`). [As an aside, even if name lookup continued into the base class scope, I don't see anything that would disambiguate between the constructor and the *injected-class-name*].

Where is my reasoning going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard goes to pains to point out that *a constructor doesn't have a name*. It can't be found by name lookup because it doesn't have a name.

C++11 §12.1/1

> **”** Constructors do not have names.

C+11 §12.1/2

> **”** Because constructors do not have names, they are
>   never found during name lookup.

Comment: What's that bit in `[class.qual] p2` that says "the name is instead considered to name the constructor" about, then?

Comment: @HighCommander4: presumably it's about using functional notation cast to invoke a constructor.

Comment: But what excludes that paragraph from applying to the `using base::base`?

Comment: sorry, i now looked up the paragraph, and it goes on to say: "Such a constructor name shall be used only in the declarator-id of
a declaration that names a constructor or in a using-declaration". There is also a note in that paragraph, saying "Note: For example, the constructor is
not an acceptable lookup result in an elaborated-type-specifier so the constructor would not be used in place
of the injected-class-name. —end note". Where are you reading this that didn't include that text?

Comment: Well, `using base::base` is a using-declaration.

Comment: Yes. And that refers to the constructor.

Comment: Then why does the constructor not become a result of member name lookup when "using-declarations are replaced by the set of designated members that are not hidden or overridden by members of the derived class"?

Comment: Can you provide a source for that quote? Not sure if I can answer it anyway, but it will sure help others.

Comment: I quoted it in my post. It's from `[class.member.lookup] p3`.

Comment: Well, the context of looking up the function result type `base` is ordinary name lookup. And then "never found during name lookup" kicks in. That's much older (from 1998) than constructor inheritance (from 2011). It may be that constructor inheritance wasn't perfectly defined. But the older rules, rule, so to speak. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess it just wasn't clear to me that one of these paragraphs takes precedence over the other.